# CASE expressions with MAX aggregate functions Oracle

Tags: oracle10g, aggregate-functions, case

Using Oracle, I have selected the title_id with its the associated month of publication with:

```
SELECT title_id, 
CASE EXTRACT(month FROM pubdate) 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Jan'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Feb'
    WHEN  3 THEN 'Mar'
    WHEN  4 THEN 'Apr'
    WHEN  5 THEN 'May'
    WHEN  6 THEN 'Jun'
    WHEN  7 THEN 'Jul'
    WHEN  8 THEN 'Aug'
    WHEN  9 THEN 'Sep'
    WHEN  10 THEN 'Oct'
    WHEN  11 THEN 'Nov'
    ELSE 'Dec'
    END MONTH 
FROM TITLES;
```

Using the statement:

```
SELECT MAX(Most_Titles) 
FROM (SELECT count(title_id) Most_Titles, month 
       FROM (SELECT title_id, extract(month FROM pubdate) AS MONTH FROM titles) GROUP BY month);
```

I was able to determine the month with the maximum number of books published.

Is there a way to join the two statements so that I can associate the month's text equivalent with the maximum number of titles?

Answer (score 3):

In order to convert a month to a string, I wouldn't use a `CASE` statement, I'd just use a `TO_CHAR`.  And you can use analytic functions to rank the results to get the month with the most books published.

```
SELECT num_titles,
       to_char( publication_month, 'Mon' ) month_str
  FROM (SELECT count(title_id) num_titles,
               trunc(pubdate, 'MM') publication_month,
               rank() over (order by count(title_id) desc) rnk
          FROM titles
         GROUP BY trunc(pubdate, 'MM'))
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

A couple of additional caveats

- If there are two months that are tied with the most publications, this query will return both rows.  If you want Oracle to arbitrarily pick one, you can use the `row_number` analytic function rather than `rank`.
- If the `PUBDATE` column in your table only has dates of midnight on the first of the month where the book is published, you can eliminate the `trunc` on the `PUBDATE` column.

Comment: Thanks from your help Justin. When I use your statement I find that I am not getting the maximum number of books. Any ideas as to what could be happening?

Comment: @user1078958 - It would help if you could post the DDL to create the table, some DML to populate some sample data, the output you expect and the output you're getting.  We're guessing a bit at what data your table actually has.  Can you explain the results you are getting and how they differ from the results you want?

Comment: Thank you for the advice regarding the DDL and some DML. It will help in future questions. As for this instance, I was finally able to get something that worked. Your help was greatly appreciated. :-)