# Oracle SQL Moderatly Complex Case Query

Tags: sql, oracle10g, case

Here is my the Problem: List the title_id, pubdate and month name (e.g., ‘May’) that has the most published books.
I'm on Oracle 10g express.
Here is my query:

```
       SELECT count(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pubdate)), title_id  
       CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pubdate)
 WHEN 2 THEN 'February'
 WHEN 3 THEN 'March'
 WHEN 4 THEN 'April'
 WHEN 5 THEN 'May'
 WHEN 6 THEN 'June'
 WHEN 7 THEN 'July'
 WHEN 8 THEN 'August'
 WHEN 9 THEN 'September'
 WHEN 10 THEN 'October'
 WHEN 11 THEN 'November'
 WHEN 12 THEN 'December'
END 
  FROM titles t, publishers p 
  WHERE t.pub_id=p.pub_id 
  AND pubdate in 
(select max(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pubdate)) from titles group by t.title_id)
GROUP BY t.title_id 
ORDER BY count(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pubdate));
```

In Oracle it is telling me that there is a FROM keyword expected not found. Any experts can look at this and tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CASE expressions with MAX aggregate functions Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407299/case-expressions-with-max-aggregate-functions-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma between `title_id  and Case`

```
SELECT count(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pubdate)), title_id , <----- comma needs to be here
       CASE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM pubdate)
 WHEN 2 THEN 'February'
 WHEN 3 THEN 'March'
 WHEN 4 THEN 'April'
 WHEN 5 THEN 'May'
 WHEN 6 THEN 'June'
 WHEN 7 THEN 'July'
 WHEN 8 THEN 'August'
 WHEN 9 THEN 'September'
 WHEN 10 THEN 'October'
 WHEN 11 THEN 'November'
 WHEN 12 THEN 'December'
END
```

Interestingly if you use [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)

You get a much better error message

> EXTRACT(2,13) expected token:**. ) , FROM INTO**